# between with values from another column

Tags: c#, mysql, count, sqldatareader

here are the contents of my table

```
tbl_range
RID // Primary Key , INT
RangeFrom // Starting Range , DOUBLE
RangeTo // End Range , DOUBLE
EE // Output , DOUBLE
```

so the query i am trying to execute is

```
SELECT EE FROM db.tbl_range WHERE RangeFrom <= @GP AND RangeTo >= @GP;
```

i tried running the query on sql and it work but in c# i't doesn't return anything, here's my code

```
cc.SetCMD("SELECT EE FROM mia_payroll.tbl_sssrange WHERE RangeFrom <= @GP AND RangeTo >= @GP;");
using (myConn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionClass.GetConnection()))
{
   myConn.Open();
   using (cmDB = new MySqlCommand(cc.GetCMD(), myConn))
   {
      cmDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GP", GP);

     try
     {
        using (myReader = cmDB.ExecuteReader())
        {
           while (myReader.Read())
           {
               ee = myReader.GetOrdinal("EE");
               lblEE.Text = System.Convert.ToString(ee);
           }
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
 }
 myReader.Close();
 myConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

and GP is user defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `GetOrdinal`, try:

```
while (myReader.Read())
{
  lblEE.Text = myReader[0].ToString();      
}
```

Comment: i asked before on what to use for getting double from sql and some answered `GetOrdinal` why is that?

Comment: GetOrdinal is used for other purposes, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong, GP must be in range

```
SELECT EE FROM db.tbl_range WHERE @GP BETWEEN RangeFrom AND RangeTo;
```